# is there a way to use dependencies injection using typescript

Tags: dependency-injection, typescript2.0

i'm relative new to this, so i want to implement dependency injection using typescript (is the first time I use this pattern), I'm more that using language programming like java or c# for OOP, so there is more easy to apply this pattern,
I found an example on internet and I can use it without problems on eclipse and visual studio, but when i use it on typescript the IDE raise an error like this:

```js
Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target
```

and is just at the end of implement it when this error appears

my base class:

```js
class Motor {
    Acelerar(): void {
    }
    GetRevoluciones(): number {
        let currentRPM: number = 0;
        return currentRPM;
    }
}
export {Motor};
```

my class that uses motor

```js
import { Motor } from "./1";
class Vehiculo {
    private m: Motor;
    public Vehiculo(motorVehiculo: Motor) {
        this.m = motorVehiculo;
    }
    public GetRevolucionesMotor(): number {
        if (this.m != null) {
            return this.m.GetRevoluciones();
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
export { Vehiculo };
```

my interface and the type of motor

```js
interface IMotor {
    Acelerar(): void;
    GetRevoluciones(): number;
}
class MotorGasoline implements IMotor {
    private DoAdmission() { }
    private DoCompression() { }
    private DoExplosion() { }
    private DoEscape() { }
    Acelerar() {
        this.DoAdmission();
        this.DoCompression();
        this.DoExplosion();
        this.DoEscape();
    }
    GetRevoluciones() {
        let currentRPM: number = 0;
        return currentRPM;
    }
}
class MotorDiesel implements IMotor {
    Acelerar() {
        this.DoAdmission();
        this.DoCompression();
        this.DoCombustion();
        this.DoEscape();
    }
    GetRevoluciones() {
        let currentRPM: number = 0;
        return currentRPM;
    }
    DoAdmission() { }
    DoCompression() { }
    DoCombustion() { }
    DoEscape() { }
}
```

and here is where the error appears:

```js
import { Vehiculo } from "./2";
enum TypeMotor {
    MOTOR_GASOLINE = 0,
    MOTOR_DIESEL = 1
}
class VehiculoFactory {
    public static VehiculoCreate(tipo: TypeMotor) {
        let v: Vehiculo = null;
        switch (tipo) {
            case TypeMotor.MOTOR_DIESEL:
                v = new Vehiculo(new MotorDiesel()); break;
            case TypeMotor.MOTOR_GASOLINE:
                v = new Vehiculo(new MotorGasoline()); break;
            default: break;
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

I don't wanna use any library or module like SIMPLE-DIJS or D4js or any other for the moment, I just wanna know how to implement without them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this error because you don't specify a constructor on the `Vehiculo` type.

To declare a constructor you should use use the `constructor` keyword and not the name of the class.

```js
class Vehiculo {
    private m: Motor;
    constructor(motorVehiculo: Motor) {
        this.m = motorVehiculo;
    }
    public GetRevolucionesMotor(): number {
        if (this.m != null) {
            return this.m.GetRevoluciones();
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that works , thanks, but do you have an idea how to put parameters into the class factory assuming than "motor gasoline" or "motor electric" has it's own constructor

Comment: I don't get it. Could you update your question with code sample and what you would like to do ?